How to find the solutions to simulteneous linear equations in mathematica, in case if the solution to them is not unique?
I have these three simultaneous equations
b+c-a-d=0; 2b-a+c=0 and c-e=0
I entered the command
Solve[{b+c-a-d==0, 2b-a+c==0, c-e==0},{b,d}]

But I got {}

Try: Solve[{b + c - a - d == 0, 2 b - a + c == 0, c - e == 0}, {b, c, d}]

Or Solve[{b + c - a - d == 0, 2 b - a + c == 0, c - e == 0}, {b, d}, {c}] or Solve[{b + c - a - d == 0, 2 b - a + c == 0, c - e == 0}, {b, d},   MaxExtraConditions -> 1]

I do not understand the votes to close. Two upvoted comments are not very informative: try this or try that and you will get the result. But no explanation. For instance, syntax with Solve[{eqs}, {vars}, {more vars}] is not known to me and I cannot find the relevant part in the documentation.

@BobHanlon Can you please explain the syntax Solve[{eqs}, {vars}, {more vars}], I cannot find in the documentation.

@yarchik -  It was documented in V7 (perhaps earlier?). See https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html While no longer documented, it still works. You can emulate this by also using Eliminate
